# Vim - errors E433 No tags file, E149 No help for help.txt

Tags: vim

I installed Git and GitHub for Windows and then I installed Vim, but I get errors - E433 No tags file, E149 No help for help.txt

I read the following:

> This is symptomatic of having installed msys-vim-bin, but not having installed msys-bin->doc; you don't get the help, without installing the documentation. I've observed the same >symptoms; the help system works fine for me, after running 'mingw-get install msys-vim-doc'.

so I installed msys-vim-doc, msys-vim-lang and msys-vim-bin, but the problem stays. Another strange thing is that when I open gvim, there is no menu (the menu where are File, Edit, View...). I tried bringing it back but again - no result.

Do you have any ideas how to fix this? Thank you very much in advance! :)

Answer (score 5):

The helpfile called *helphelp.txt* in my Win32 GVim installation has this to say about helpfiles:

> When no argument is given to **|:help|** the file given with the
>   '**helpfile**' option will be opened.  Otherwise the specified tag is
>   searched for in all "doc/tags" files in the directories specified in
>   the '**runtimepath**' option.

So if you enter

```
:echo &helpfile
```

you should see where your Vim expects to find the help-file.
And:

```
:echo &runtimepath
```

will list the locations where Vim will look for a **doc** subfolder containing the help files.
(Mine are in `C:\Program Files\vim\vim73\doc`)

If the installation of msys-vim-doc put the documentation somewhere not listed in &runtimepath, you will have to add that location to your runtimepath, by putting something like this in your `.vimrc`

```
set &rtp+=/parent/of/the/docs/dir
```

On reflection, since your menus are missing too, I suspect that your runtimepath or the directories if refers to are completely hosed. Is there also something like an `msys-vim-runtime` package that you need to install?

If all else fails, you could download the source tarball from [www.vim.org](http://www.vim.org/), extract it and then

```
./configure
make
make install
```